# Can't load email template nodejs nginx

Tags: node.js, nginx, nodemailer

I run a little node app on my nginx ubuntu server. I managed to get the site up and running with serving all static files. (took me a while to figure that one out).

But now I want to run a cron job to send an email. In this email I load a simple html template using 'fs'. When I run the cron job it gives me the error:

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'email.html'

I think is again due to not finding static files but don't know how to fix it. Because I don't use express to run this script. My script.js looks like this:

```
'use strict';
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var ejs = require("ejs");
var fs = require("fs");
var Handlebars = require('handlebars');

var source = fs.readFileSync('email.html','utf8');

var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

var result = template(user);

var mailOptions = {
    from: '"Me, <me@gmail.com>', // sender address
    to: "user@user.com", // list of receivers
    subject: 'subject', // Subject line
    html: result
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
    if (error) {
        return console.log(error);
    }
    console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);
    console.log('Preview URL: %s', nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));
    process.exit()
});
```

script.js and email.html are in the same root folder

My nginx file looks like this:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name roostr.online www.roostr.online;

        location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000/;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        }

        location ~ ^/(images/|img/|javascript/|html/|js/|css/|stylesheets/|flash/|media/|static/|robots.txt|humans.txt|favicon.ico) {
                 root /var/www/roostr.online/html/public;
                access_log off;
                expires max;
        }
    }
```

Comment: var html = fs.readFileSync('./path/email.html', 'utf8');

Comment: thanks, needed a night of sleep to find this obvious one.

Comment: I have posted the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var html = fs.readFileSync('./path/email.html', 'utf8');
```